# How to use Identity user managament with Cordova and OAuth.io?

Tags: c#, facebook, cordova, oauth, asp.net-identity

I want to make a Cordova phone app and a web application. Both the application and the app share the same database.

On the mobile app, the user actions send requests to a web service ( over https ) that writes to the database. On the mobile app, I use https://oauth.io to let the user register and log in with multiple open auth providers.  Trying to make it work for facebook, for now.

I just can't figure how to use the Identity user management in that context. Most of the examples I find are in the context of a web app where the user clicks and it calls the account controller. In my case, the oauth.io lib calls facebook, returns an access token, which I pass to my service.

The cordova app passes the accessToken to this method to my server side web service.

```
var client = new FacebookClient(accessToken);

if (client != null)
{
    dynamic fbresult = client.Get("me");

    if (fbresult["id"] != null)
    {

        var fbid = fbresult["id"].ToString();

        and where do we go from now ?
        how do I insert a new user
```

I tried this:

```
var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = fbresult["id"] };
Backend.Controllers.AccountController ac = new Controllers.AccountController();
ac.UserManager.CreateAsync(user);
```

Doesn't work because the usermanagement object inside the account controller is null.
There is an overload of the AccountController constructor but I have a feeling I'm doing this whole thing the wrong way.

Let's say the server side receives a facebook access token. How do use OWIN and Identity user management system from there?

Comment: gunr2171 you are changing the context and the steps of the post with the sentences you're adding.

Comment: I only replaced your headers with words that I thought was equivalent. No need to say it was [sabotage](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26937406/3). Also, you should really remove the "Question: " from your last paragraph, it's noise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok.

As suggested by a friend, **I replaced the controllers etc from the original web api template** for the ones in the [Identity Sample Project](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Samples)

Here is the method called by the mobile app, with a angular jsonp

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public string StartSession(string accessToken)
{
    if (!HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        var client = new FacebookClient(accessToken);

        if (client != null)
        {
            dynamic fbresult = client.Get("me");

            if (fbresult["id"] != null)
            {
                string fbid = fbresult["id"].ToString();

                ApplicationUser user = null;

                using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
                {
                    user = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName.ToString() == fbid);
                }

                if (user == null)
                {
                    CreateUserAsync(fbid);
                    return "user created. ";
                }
                else
                {
                    HttpContext.Current.Session["user"] = "holy fuck";                                                  
                    return "user logged in. ";
                }
            }
        }
        return "ok";
    }
    else
    {
        return "already auth !";
    }
}
```

here is the CreateUserAsync I made

```
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<bool> CreateUserAsync(string fbid)
{

    using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
    {

        var newUser = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = fbid, Email = "xxx@gmail.com" }; 
        var userManager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));

        try
        {
            var result = await userManager.CreateAsync(newUser, "Admin@123456");
            var test   = await context.SaveChangesAsync();                    

            return result.Succeeded;                   
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

And then, when the mobile app calls back my web service, I can check if the session exists like so:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public async Task<string> TestLogin(int id, string callback)
{

    if (HttpContext.Current.Session["user"] != null)
    {
        return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new word() { Name = "woot" });        
    }
    else
        return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new word() { Name = "not logged" });
}
```

Yea, that's right. A if and a session. Just like I was doin' 13 years ago.

Also, while doing this abomination, I stumbled upon a hangin' problem in the IdentityConfig.cs file.

Apparantly, the problem is known by Microsoft and I guess it is probably fixed in the version 3 of Owin ? But I didn't know about that version 3 at that time, so I followed [Program hangs during database initialization](http://forums.asp.net/post/5802779.aspx) .

For some reason, some of the method posted in his solution didn't exist for me. I ended up fixing the code the best I could:

```
public static void InitializeIdentityForEF(ApplicationDbContext db)
{
    //ApplicationUserManager userManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
    RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(db));

    const string name = "admin@example.com";
    const string password = "Admin@123456";
    const string roleName = "Admin";

    IdentityRole adminRole = new IdentityRole(roleName);


    //Create Role Admin if it does not exist
    if (!roleManager.RoleExists(roleName))
    {
        roleManager.Create(adminRole);

        PasswordHasher hasher = new PasswordHasher();

        ApplicationUser adminUser = new ApplicationUser { UserName = name, Email = name, PasswordHash = hasher.HashPassword(password), LockoutEnabled = false };
        db.Users.Add(adminUser);

        IdentityUserRole userRole = new IdentityUserRole() { RoleId  = adminRole.Id, UserId = adminUser.Id };
        adminUser.Roles.Add(userRole);

        var x = db.SaveChanges();

    }

}
```

Also just in case someone is wondering how to call the svc service from the mobile, here is the  code.

(it's a little bit messy, but the important parts are there.)
(keep in mind I am using https://oauth.io/ )

```
$scope.refresh = function () {

$http.jsonp("https://10.0.100.38:6443/Service1.svc/helloworld?id=1&callback=JSON_CALLBACK").success(function JSON_CALLBACK(result) {

    OAuth.popup('facebook')
   .done(function (oauthResult) {

       oauthResult.me() // standardise lesfield firstname, first-name etc
       .done(function (response) {
           alert("3");


           $http.jsonp("https://10.0.100.38:6443/Service1.svc/StartSession?accessToken=" +oauthResult.access_token + "&callback=JSON_CALLBACK").success(function JSON_CALLBACK(result) {
               alert("done " +result); // StartSession serverside success ");

    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                   alert("icierror2" +data + " " +status + " " +headers + " " + config);

               $scope.status = status;
               });
       }).fail(function (error) {
           alert("icierror3 " +error);
       });
       })
   .fail(function (error) {
       console.log(error);
});

    alert(result.Name); // result de la svc request over https

    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        alert("icierror" +data + " " +status + " " + headers + " " +config);

    $scope.status = status;
});
```

### Problems

As of now, I am not creating a Login, only a user is created.

Also, the project's OWIN version is 2.0, and apparantly, a 3.0 exists.

To be honest, the more I read online the more I feel like everything I've done is a big hack around the right way to do it. I just couldn't figure it out. This is thing is incredibly huge, confusing, chaothic and broken. Yea, I've added an opinion to my answer.